# How to cast this type?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have this class:

```
 public class Response<T>
{
    public Response(T data, string msg, bool error)
    {
        Data = data;
        Message = msg;
        Error = error;
    }

    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Error { get; set; }
}
```

and then I have a response method that return this Response class with a particular T, for example `Response<int>`

But it return as TResponse, because is a return from a generic method (from all the Handlers with MediatR)

So I have:

```
var result = await next();
```

that return a TResponse type con "result".

and a I want to cast that in order to do something like this:

```
        Response<T> response = (Response<T>)result;

        logMsg += $"Response status: {(response.Error ? "FAIL" : "OK")}" + Environment.NewLine;
        logMsg += $"Response message: {response.Message}" + Environment.NewLine;
```

but of course, that cast doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This question needs to be improved to be answerable. What is the signature of `next()`? What is the scope of your last code snippet? What is "TResponse"?

Comment: *I have a response method* Can you edit your question to include its code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of casting, maybe add an interface which lets you access the message and the error properties regardless of type `T`.

```
public interface IResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Error { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : IResponse
{
    public Response(T data, string msg, bool error)
    {
        Data = data;
        Message = msg;
        Error = error;
    }

    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Error { get; set; }
}
```